# Auction style countdown timer JS, ASP.net, SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, datetime, timer

I'm trying to display a countdown timer for Number of Days,Hours,Minutes,Seconds left until Auction is over on my website.

I've followed this tutorial for a countdown timer:
https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

My problem is i'm storing a datetime timestamp in my SQL table that says when the auction is over and I can pull this into my website via a Token but it would be in this format `2017-01-02 03:00:00.000` in the JS file of the example at the bottom it's in this format: `var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`

I've found the following article that explains how to take my datetime column in SQL an pull minutes, seconds, hours but it's not all on 1 field.
http://sqlhints.com/2014/02/23/how-to-get-time-hour-minute-second-and-millisecond-part-from-datetime-in-sql-server/

I'm not sure how to modify this JS so that it can read my end date/time from the table directly in it's native datetime format.

JS:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Comment: Take a look at moment.js (http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/). It should have what you need.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt Thank you i'll review it.